# How can I share test code between Rust crates in a workspace?

Tags: testing, rust

I have several crates in a workspace. One crate define a Trait, that others implement. I would like to write a few test functions that just take the Trait and ensure all the invariants are always true, and that sample code work with all instances of the Trait. So I'd like to define a test suite, and each other crate should say "I define my tests as being this test suite, with my own implementation of the Trait". Is that possible?

I suppose I could define a macro in my library that generates all the tests using the Trait instance, but that would mix production and test code in my library. Can another crate in my workspace reference a test module present in the tests folder of my main crate?

So basically I have:

```
workspace
|-- crate1
    |-- src
        |-- lib.rs
    |-- tests
        |-- harness.rs
|-- crate2
    |-- src
        |-- lib.rs
    |-- tests
        |-- test2.rs
```

And I would like `test2.rs` to be able to use `harness.rs`. Is that possible?

Comment: add crate (dev ?) dependencies

Comment: Add which dependency? crate2 already depends on crate1, but cannot access the test crates. Is there a way to add a dependency to a test crate?

Comment: ahhh no this is not possible do a utils crate 3

Comment: OK, so I either just add modules in my crate1 even it they're really only useful for tests or add a new utility crate as you suggest, thanks. Add this as an answer if you want, @Stargateur

Comment: I'm not good in english as this answer will need a lot of text I pass :p

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306248/share-common-test-code-between-multiple-packages-in-rust

Answer (score 3):

You can share code between crates by using a `path` attribute:

```rust
#[path="../shared/my_utils.rs"]
mod utils;
```