# Share common test code between multiple packages in rust

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-cargo

I am having common functionality that I want to reuse in junit tests that live in different packages and I don't know how to do it. I've tried with different modules and libs but something is not working. My current structure looks something like this:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── foo
│   └── bar
│       └── baz
│           ├── template
│           │    ├── Cargo.lock
│           │    ├── Cargo.toml
│           │    └── src
│           │        └── tests
│           │            ├── mod.rs
│           │            └── test1.rs
│           │
│           └── template_implementation
│                 ├── Cargo.lock
│                 ├── Cargo.toml
│                 └── src
│                     └── tests
│                         ├── mod.rs
│                         └── test2.rs
│
└── utils
    └── testpackage
        ├── Cargo.toml
        ├── lib.rs
        └── common.rs
```

So in `common.rs` I have something like this:

```
/// setup for tests
pub fn setup() { ... }
pub fn mock_x() { ... }
pub fn mock_y() { ... }
```

`lib.rs` looks like this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod common;
```

I want to use those functions in `common.rs` in both `test1.rs` and `test2.rs`. I made sure dependencies are correct on the cargo files, and even though they are "found" by the IDE, I get an error when doing `cargo test` that the methods are not found in `testpackage`.

It "works" if I remove `#[cfg(test)]` from the mod but I don't want that to be included when doing `cargo build`, besides I get bunch of warnings when running the tests and it doesn't even compile the artifacts then.

I tried moving `common.rs` around, to include it in the `template` package for example but still couldn't get it work, I face similar issues. Not sure if I am missing some annotation or what, if feels like a very silly issue.

How would you do something like this?

Comment: How does this question relate to JUnit?

Comment: Right, wrong tag

Comment: This looks like a rather unconventional Rust project folder structure... are you using Cargo workspaces or something to manage that?

Comment: I am using cargo sure, I am having multiple crates to separate concerns, what's unconventional about it? @Sty

Comment: I find the nesting levels unconventional (with `foo/bar/baz/` layers above two folders with actual crate definitions), but then again you may be just omitting irrelevant code base parts

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch (I haven't tried to recreate your folder structure there and never tried to compile a `#[cfg(test)]` library), but by the way it looks you're juggling three different crates in a workspace setup. In this case your `testpackage` would (to my understanding) only be included as a pseudo-external dependency in your `template` and `template_implementation` crates. To my understanding of the workspaces build process, workspace sub-crates will be compiled for debug or release (but never in testing configuration) for inclusion in other sub-crates of a workspace, while `#[cfg(test)]` is only ever used within the scope of a single crate.

Comment: That might explain why the IDE finds it yet it's not possible to run the tests... how would you achieve something like that instead? Do you see a better way to do it?

Comment: Difficult if you want to maintain basically entirely separate crates, in that case I'd think your best bet is to not use `#cfg[test]` for your utils crate, but to set it up in a way that it's only included in the other crates as a `dev-dependency`. Personally, though, I'd wonder if you really need a separate-crates structure, or if namespacing or feature flags wouldn't perhaps already solve the separation of concerns sufficiently, while still allowing test-relevant code to reside in the same crate scope

Comment: Thanks for the idea, will look into it.